# Html getting innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have added an onClick event to anchor tag, when the user clicks on it. I have to get the inner html without using the id attribute.Following is the code what i am using. Please help me to achieve this.

```
function bttnpressed()
{
   alert('inside bttnpressed');
}
<a onclick="bttnpressed()">name1</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**innerHTML**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp) property. You need to pass the source of event to `click` event which could be passed using `this`.

```
function bttnpressed(obj)
{
   alert('inside bttnpressed');
   alert(obj.innerHTML);
}
<a onclick="bttnpressed(this)">name1</a>
```

Comment: Hi Adil, thanks for your answer. it woks fine, i think instead of this.innerHTML should be obj.innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

This will do

```
function bttnpressed(Currnt)
{
    alert('inside bttnpressed ' + Currnt.innerHTML);
 }


<a onclick="bttnpressed(this)">name1</a>
```